# How do I find the eigenvalues (and eigenfunctions) of this Sturm Liouville problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I'm trying to solve an S-L problem, but I'm finding it difficult to find any solved examples of equations that aren't in the form of $y''=\pm \lambda y$.

Instead, it's in the following form:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \bigg[-e^{ax}\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg]-e^{ax}y\bigg[1+\lambda\bigg] = 0$$

(I'm leaving out the exact value of a, and the given conditions, because I don't want an exact solution, but can someone please explain how I'm supposed to go about this? What I'm trying is setting $\lambda = 0$, $\lambda > 0$, and $\lambda < 0$. (I've already checked for $\lambda = 0$, and got a trivial solution, but I have yet to try both other conditions). Anyway, is this enough? Or is there a different way to actually get a solution?

I would really appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
     -e^{ax}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-ae^{ax}\frac{dy}{dx}-e^{ax}y\left[1+\lambda\right]=0 \\
       \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a\frac{dy}{dx}+(1+\lambda)y=0.
$$
This is a linear ODE with constant coefficients.

From your comment, you want conditions
$$
           y(0)=0,\; y'(\pi)-y(\pi)=0.
$$
You have solutions $e^{mx}$ where $m$ satisfies
$$
             m^2+am+(1+\lambda)=0 \\
            (m+a/2)^2+(1+\lambda)-a^2/4=0 \\
         m+a/2 =\pm\sqrt{a^2/4-(1+\lambda)} \\
        m=-a/2\pm\sqrt{a^2/4-(1+\lambda)}
$$
A solution with $y(0)=0$ is
$$
      y(x)=e^{-ax/2}\sinh(\sqrt{a^2/4-(1+\lambda)}\,x)
$$
Then the eigenvalue equation becomes
$$
        y'(\pi)-y(\pi)=0.
$$
The $\sinh$ becomes $\sin$ if the argument of $\sinh$ is purely imaginary, and that's what I would expect here.

Comment: Yes, it does become a linear ODE. But, how am I supposed to find the eigenvalues? I don't think I can set $\lambda >0$ or $<0$, since they won't give me conclusive answers for the eigenvalues. Do I set it as $\lambda<1$, $=1$ and $>1$?

Comment: @Applesauce44 : What interval are you working on? If this is a finite interval, what endpoint conditions are you assuming?

Comment: $0 \leq x \leq \pi$,   $y(0)=0$,   $y'(\pi)-y(\pi)=0$. These are given conditions+interval.

Comment: @Applesauce44 : I added a few more things to the post for you.

Comment: Ahhh I see. This is helpful! Thank you!